# CSS menu last-child z-index

Tags: css

I am trying apply a background image to a `li:last-child>a` element in a menu that I need to `z-index` over everything else and can't seem to get it to work.

The image extending the parent container and clipping off the bottom of the image. Can be seen at http://cgrande.development.webdesign-toledo.com/

CSS:

```
#user-menu .nav>li:last-child>a {
    background: url(tag.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 66px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 20px 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Css `z-index` works on non-static element, that is, add `position: relative` or `position: absolute` for `z-index` to take effect.

**edit** As i can see, last child height is too small for all image to appear. Increase last child's `<a>` element height to see full background image.

Comment: i had already added position relative to #user-menu .nav>li missed that in my code above, am I not applying the position property to the right element?

Comment: @TENDesign you have to apply position property to that element where you apply z-index